# Akka Essentials using Java 8: return Result for first example

Tags: java, akka, reactive-programming

I write my first reactive app with Akka using the example of Akka Essentials Book, but when i want to print the Result object show a empty value '{}'. The Result should be: '{galaxia, lejana, mucho, tiempo, vivia, guerrero, esperada, encontrarse}'. This example was originally worked with akka 2.0.3.

My pom file invokes akka 2.4.16 and my project has no errors, someone can help me?.

All source code is [here](https://github.com/randiel/wogo).

```
public class MapReduceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ActorSystem _system = ActorSystem.create("MapReduceApp");
        ActorRef master = _system.actorOf(Props.create(MasterActor.class),"master");

        master.tell("en una galaxia lejana hace mucho mucho tiempo", ActorRef.noSender());
        master.tell("vivia un guerrero que esperaba encontrarse con el guerrero de una galaxia proxima", ActorRef.noSender());

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        Result msg = new Result();
        Timeout timeout = new Timeout(Duration.create(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        Future<Object> future = Patterns.ask(master, msg, timeout);
        String result = (String) Await.result(future, timeout.duration());
        System.out.println(result);
        _system.terminate();
    }

}
```

Comment: ...so, what `MasterActor` do? And what's `Result`?

Comment: all source code in: https://github.com/randiel/wogo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have problem with definition of aggregate actor. it shouldn't be routed to pool of 5 actors, instead it should be only 1 that aggregates all the data
you can fix your code by changing it to

```
ActorRef aggregateActor = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(AggregateActor.class),"aggregate");
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. That is actually the way the code is written in the Akka Essentials book.

Comment: Thank you! a lot!